# Is there any shorthand for WPF column and row definitions?

Tags: wpf

I have a simple grid layout which is just hosting several labels and textboxes. Labels in the first column, boxes in the second.

Whenever I add a new box, I have to add an empty `<RowDefinition />` in to my `<Grid.RowDefinitions>` block to allow it to occupy a new row. Since I don't have any style attached to these rows, is there some sort of shorthand that would prevent having to to this?

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition />
  <RowDefinition />
  <RowDefinition />
  <RowDefinition />
  <RowDefinition />
  <RowDefinition />
  <RowDefinition />
  <RowDefinition />
  <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't a short hand method for this, but you could write your own solution, or use a framework where someone already has.

For example, the [CODE framework](http://codeframework.codeplex.com/) allows you to define markup as shown in Listing 6 [here](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=1201061&page=4). This uses a custom panel to greatly simplify the definition of common editing forms.

You could download the [source](http://codeframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) and have a look at their implementation and tailor it for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, CODE is probably a bit overkill for my little one-off app, but I'll keep it for future projects

Comment: I have just submitted a suggestion for this idea.  If you agree then [please go and add your vote](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/13962687-wpf-grid-column-height-definition-shorthand).

Answer (score 5):

You could use an Attached Property to create a shorthand syntax on your own.

I've created a sample here: https://github.com/thomasclaudiushuber/Wpf-Grid-Extensions

It allows you to write this:

```
<Grid local:GridExtensions.Structure="*,100|200,*">

</Grid>
```

And behind the scenes it creates this:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass Grid and add any behavior you need.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/3011104/90987f2f15ef87764481d94d0e3ebf7f759f1ce8) is an implementation of `AutoGrid` that automatically inserts new rows for any `AutoGridEndRow` object as well as whenever `Grid.Row` is larger than current definitions count.

Usage as below:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
  <my:AutoGrid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Label1" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" />
    <my:AutoGridEndRow />

    <Label Content="Label1" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" />

  </my:AutoGrid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this, it looks like a pretty slick way to get this done.